# Multilevel subdomains on ubuntu server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, subdomain

here is an issue there related to my dev server configuration (Ubuntu Server with LAMP installed)

I have a subdomain which is pointing to my server something like http://sudomain.domain.com.

Now I need to make some subdomains on my server each domain to point to a separate folder on the server /var/www/proj1 should be loaded by accessing http://proj1.subdomain.domain.com, 
http://proj2.subdomain.domain.com

Can anyone help me fix this issue? Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

What you'll need is the Apache VirtualHost directive.
See the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/en/vhosts/) and some [Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/vhosts/examples.html).

Basically what you want to do in Ubuntu is to make sure, that the port you want to use (usually :80) is enabled in /etc/apache2/ports.conf like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

Next you'll have to create a new conf-file in /etc/apache2/sites-available.
I'd suggest to name it proj1.conf or proj1.mydomain.conf.

There you can configure the VirtualHost as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName proj1.subdomain.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/proj1
  ServerAdmin name@domain.com

  # Write a seperate log per Virtualhost
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/proj1.subdomain.access_log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/proj1.subdomain.error_log

  # Maybe you want to put some restrictions on the directory
  <Directory /var/www/proj1>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks + Includes
    AllowOverride All
    # Restrict Access to certain IP's
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 IP IP IP
    Satisfy ALL
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Consult the Apache Manual to see what you could do with the  Directive.

To enable this Site, link it to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/proj1.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/proj1
```

Now all you have to do is make sure your config is valid and then restart Apache:

```
apache2ctl configtest && /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Naturally you will have to set up the subdomain in your DNS in a way that it points to this server.